# First and Second order PDF for continuous-time stochastic process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Given:
$$ x(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\cos \omega_1 t & : P =0.5\\
\cos \omega_2 t & : P=0.5
\end{array}
\right. $$

where $\omega_{1,2}$ are two different known frequencies.

What would the first order and second order PDF's be?

From what I know is that $F(x,t)=P[X(t) \leq x]$ and that the first order PDF is $f(x,t) = \frac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial x}$. As for the second order PDF $ f(x_1,x_2,t_1,t_2) = \frac{\partial^2 F(x_1,x_2,t_1,t_2)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}$.

I doubt that the first and second order PDF end up being $0$ since I am thinking that $F(x,t)=0.5$. What else am I missing?

Comment: No random variable $x(t)$ has a PDF.

Comment: This is originally a Qualifying exam study question, so is this meant to be a trick question? I was normally under the impression that the PDF was associated with some random variable typically for this type of problem it is some like $\cos ( \omega t + \theta)$ where $\theta$ is a random variable with some distribution in some interval.

Comment: If $\omega$ is constant and $\theta$ is random and has a PDF then $\cos(\omega t+\theta)$ has a PDF.

Comment: That is what I thought and why this problem has felt so odd to solve. I thought I may have to treat this problem more like a discrete stochastic process to determine the first order and second order statistics. Thank you for your help.